# Is the autocovariance function of a sequence identically zero if the sequence is iid?

Tags: stochastic-processes, correlation, covariance

My professor gives the following definition for the autocovariance function. $$\rho(i,j) = Cov(X_i , X_j)$$$\\$If I have a sequence that is *iid*, when i compute $\rho(n,n+1)$ for $n \geq 0$, I found that it is always zero (since they are independent). Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since $X_i$ and $X_j$ are *independent* for $i \neq j$, their covariance
is $0$, and hence the autocovariance function has value $0$ for all $i \neq j$.
Note that *identical* distribution is not needed for this result to hold;
independence suffices.  In fact, all that is needed is for $X_i$ and $X_j$ to
be *uncorrelated* for all $i \neq j$, which is true when the random variables
are independent, but can also happen without independence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, except for a minor technical condition pertaining to the existence of moments, eg Cauchy distribution.